# Is it possible to push to a new remote on VSTS git?

Tags: azure-devops

Is it possible to create a new VSTS Git remote repository from a Git client?

Right now, I have to go to visualstudio.com first to create the new repository **before** adding and pushing it from PC git, using the url created in VSTS.

I tried the following:

```
git remote add brandnew xx.visualstudio.com/PROJECT/_git/qqq
git push brandnew --all
```

where I am the owner of xx.visualstudio.com and PROJECT is an existing project, but `qqq` *does not exist*.

The above gives me:

> remote: TF401019: The Git repository with name or identifier qqq does not exist or you do not have permissions for the operation you are attempting.
>
> fatal: repository 'https://xx.visualstudio.com/PROJECT/_git/qqq/' not found

Comment: I think I did it from Visual Studio

Comment: I think I have done that too, but I have since moved away from Visual Studio in favor of VS Code.

Comment: not sure about VS Code, but did you try from command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

Even you can not create a VSTS git repo by git command line by default, but you can achieve it via **git hooks**.

And for the reason why you can create and publish new VSTS git repo via VS, it that VS will create the new VSTS git repo by API not by git commands.

So if you want achieve this feature in git command line, you can use **pre-push hook** for assistance. Functions need to achieve in pre-push hook as below:

- Detect if the remote repo https://xx.visualstudio.com/PROJECT/_git/qqq exist or not.
- If the repo is not exist in VSTS, then [create by REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/git/repositories/create?view=vsts-rest-4.1).

Comment: I have been using this method, but it requires that I first go to visualstudio.com to create the repository to get the url. I tried by using a new url imitating the same style, ie `xx.visualstudion.com/PROJECTNAME/_git/newrepositoryname` and it won't work. It says `TF401019: The Git repository with name or identifier newrepositoryname does not exist or you do not have permissions for the operation you are attempting. fatal: repository 'https://xx.visualstudio.com/PROJECTNAME/_git/newrepositoryname' not found.`

Comment: Yes, you should create the git repo in VSTS firstly. Else git can not find where to push.

Comment: A new repo can be created and pushed from Visual Studio though.

Comment: @OldGeezer Did the answer help you solve your problem?

Comment: It solves the problem in that I have to create the repository first from the web site, which I was doing before posing the question. It does not answer the question because I was hoping to create the repository by a `git push` command.

Comment: @OldGeezer I updated my answer. So if you want to create VSTS git repo, you can add the related functions in pre-push hook in your local git repo.